# Global path not found by Emscripten when using CMake

Tags: c++, emscripten

I'm trying to see if it is possible to run Emscripten using CMake as the Makefile generator. My generate command is:

`cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=emcc -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include ../`

The `-DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` shouldn't be necessary but I added it when I got the error:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
ERROR    root: compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
```

My project only contains GLM as a dependency (edit: also depends on C++11), and if I wasn't using `emcc` as my compiler it would normally get picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the compiler in the cmake call is not enough, you need the toolchain. To do that, use `emcmake cmake [options]`. It will set everything you need to compile using emscripten.